# Can you travel from Northern Ireland to Britain without a passport or driver's license?

Tags: uk, northern-ireland

Can you travel from Northern Ireland to Britain without a passport or driver's license? In theory there are no border checks but ferries seem to demand photo ID.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The principles:

- There is no border between NI and England, therefore there are (in theory) no border checks.
- As a UK citizen in the UK, there is no obligation to carry any form of ID.

However, in practice there may be officers checking people and asking for ID as they disembark.  If you had none, then they could reasonably detain you for a short time while verifying your identity in some other way.  Therefore it is advised to carry some form of ID (I used a railcard, but a bank card should suffice).

Comment: But can you actually get on a ferry or aeroplane without the id?

Comment: Not sure about an aeroplane, but there are no ID checks before boarding the ferry.

Comment: Interesting. So for the ferry you are checked as you disembark and  non photo id such as a bank card will do?  (A bank card is not really a form of id so I find this surprising.  A utility bill even less so.) Does this mean that people too young to have bank cards/utility bills can't travel on their own from NI to Britain?

Comment: @eleanora Firstly it's a case of *may* be checked, not *are* checked. Secondly, they're really looking for evidence of legal status within the country, not proof of id.

Comment: @origimbo Right but from the point of view of the traveller, "may be checked" is enough to make sure you try not to get in trouble.  Possession of a bank card is not really proof of anything to be honest.  To start with, they would have no idea whose bank card it was.

Comment: Yes and no.  The reason is that it isn't a formal 'ID' check (as that would be unacceptable politically).  It is much more informal.  If you look/sound British and show a British birth certificate/bank card/vaguely official document with your name on it/etc then you will be waved through.

Comment: @MarkPerryman Fascinating. That seems to be begging for a discrimination court case! I mean how do you look/sound British? Say you are wearing muslim dress and have a strong Pakistani accent, as many UK citizens do and have..

Comment: @eleanora Then you either show your evidence, or are grossly inconvenienced while it's checked you aren't involved in people trafficking. In the worst case, both. Note that the same kind of thing applies when you get a job or rent property.

Comment: (I am now guessing) If you have a strong Pakistani accent and show a standard Barclays bank card reading Ahmed Hassan then you are probably fine.  If they instead showed a bank card reading John Smith and responded to further questions in broken English then they might well ask some more questions.  If they were aggressive or furtive then further investigations might follow.  The police are entitled to take reasonable measures to check your entitlement to be in the UK anywhere.  I'm sure they know the limits of 'reasonable' and do not open themselves up to a court case.

Comment: Thanks for all these answers. It's clearer to me that if you wanted to get from NI to Britain illegally as a non-UK citizen it wouldn't be hard at all. Given that they are both in the UK I can see that isn't a political problem. What I find odd is why they bother to check id at all given how ineffective it must be.

Comment: When I travelled it was just three policemen standing in a corridor.  Gives them something to do I guess.

Comment: @eleanora 'if you wanted to get from NI to Britain illegally as a non-UK citizen it wouldn't be hard at all' . But, but... that's like saying if you want to get from Kensington to Cardiff illegally as a non-UK citizen... it's nonsensical. You cant be legal to be in NI and not legal to be in GB, there is one status across the state called *The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern ireland*. if there is an issue it's at the NI border with the Republic, but that's covered by the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)

Comment: I guess this hasn't lasted well. You can get from Ireland to NI and then from NI to Britain without ever showing id

Answer (score 6):

https://www.irishferries.com/ie-en/frequently-asked-questions/top-10-faqs/passports-identification/

https://www.stenaline.co.uk/faqs/passports-and-visas/im-a-british-irish-citizen-do-i-need-a-passport-to-travel
https://www.stenaline.co.uk/faqs/passports-and-visas/im-a-citizen-of-a-non-eu-country-is-there-anything-else-i-need-to-do

Non-UK and non-Irish nationals require a passport, according to this web page at Irish Ferries.

Stena Line, which sails from Northern Ireland to Great Britain, is somewhat more vague about requirements (see links above).

Identification is required even on Northern Ireland to Great Britain ferries, such as:

- passport
- driver's license
- European identity card
- bank cards
- photo ID (school or college)
- utility bills
- birth certificate

So, strictly speaking, it appears as though photo ID is not required, but some sort of verification of your identity is.

Comment: Can you really travel just with your credit card as id? I don’t really understand it as you would need a passport to know if you are non-uk/non-Irish or not.

Comment: @elanora you've stumbled on the great paradox of ID requirements that apply only to certain people. How can those to whom the requirement does not apply prove it without ID? We have a similar problem here in the US.

Comment: @eleanora I'm just the messenger :) but if you're a foreigner, using your passport seems the safest bet, or your EU identity card if you're an EU citizen. But they could probably tell a non-local credit card.  Doesn't help if you're a foreign resident, I suppose.

Comment: Sorry about shooting the messenger :) But I do wonder what happens in practice.

Comment: @eleanora :) If you find out, please post another comment and let us know.

Comment: That may not be the best link to prove the NI situation, given that those routes all seem to be to the Republic...

Comment: @origimbo I thought I saw that they sailed NI-GB as well, but perhaps I was mistaken.  I added citations from Stena Line and they are somewhat vaguer.  I suspect the requirements are similar to Irish Ferries in practice.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, In practice I've taken Irish Ferries from Holyhead to Dublin and back with a car twice without ever being asked for personal ID at all. They used the car's registration plate to find the booking (a walk-on passenger might need something with their name on it for the same purpose). I understand they sometimes run immigration spot checks at the arrival end, which is when a passport becomes relevant, but I've yet to see one on my trips to the Republic and I don't know if they do that for ferries to/from Belfast.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie what if you're Irish or British but you only have non-local credit cards?

Comment: @Dennis this makes sense.  No private company will want to get into the business of judging whether people who can't show a passport or national ID card are in fact Irish or British citizens.

Comment: @Dennis The NI/Ireland border is completely open without checks if you travel by car.  The Ireland/Britain border is a different question,   It’s travelling from NI to Britain that I don’t understand.

Comment: @phoog They may not prefer to, but it then becomes a question of whether they're happier to annoy their customers by requiring them to carry evidence (not proof) of identity, or the authorities by not doing to.

Comment: @origimbo Dennis's experience suggests that the authorities do not hold the companies responsible for enforcing a policy that requires ID only in certain (difficult to determine) circumstances.  For them to do so would be at least unreasonable, if not illegal.  So I guess the authorities don't get too annoyed.