# What ID does an 11 year old need for the ferry to Belfast?

Tags: uk, ferries, northern-ireland

My 19 year old son is travelling to Belfast by ferry. He has got a passport, but he is travelling with a 11 year old who has got no photo Id. What will he need to take?

Comment: That is it the question? Belfast UK, right? (Probably there are many other Belfast in US, Canada, Australia, etc.). Ferry from where? UK? Ireland? Isle of Man? France? Norway?

Comment: In addition to @GiacomoCatenazzi's questions, it's likely that the answer depends on the child's nationality.  I suppose from the fact that the child has no photo ID that the child is either British or Irish.  Is that correct?

Comment: While these questions are legit, if the ferry is from anywhere other than the UK then the child will need a travel document. So I think it's safe to assume they mean from the UK.

Comment: Have you checked the ferry company’s website? Eg StenaLine policy accepts a birth certificate to prove ID for children aged up to 17 years https://www.stenaline.co.uk/faqs/passports-and-visas/im-a-british-irish-citizen-do-i-need-a-passport-to-travel but others may have a different policy https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112000/can-you-travel-from-northern-ireland-to-britain-without-a-passport-or-drivers-l